# Ajax validation in Yii form

Tags: ajax, validation, yii

In my form I want to make an ajax validation for the radio buttons of gender.

I have an attribute `gender` in the model `users`, at the rules of model I put `gender` as a required field, but when I submit the form without selecting any gender the validation doesn't work to tell me that the gender cannot be blank, here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'gender'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'gender',array('value'=>'0')) . 'Male<br>'; ?>
  <?php echo $form->radioButton($model,'gender',array('value'=>'1')) . 'Female'; ?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'gender'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using radioButtonList() instead of radioButton().

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'gender'); ?>
<?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'gender',array('1'=>'Male','2'=>'Female')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'gender'); ?>
```

Comment: What happens that makes you believe the problem is not solved?